# gulp not running the tasks in windows fresh install

Tags: node.js, gulp

installed node on fresh win 8.1 os and installed gulp
global.

checked install by checking versions of them using -v flag.
shows no problems there.

I made a dummy project to test gulp with gulp-sass.
when i ran gulp for first time windows asked which software to open files with. so i checked sublime text.

now when i run gulp the gulp.js file opens in sublime text instead of gulp
running the task in gulp.js

no errors and nothing shows in cmd. Any idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: By _run gulp_ you mean from the command line and not just by opening the file right? Just clarifying.

Comment: yes, run gulp in cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in one of two ways , First one is : you will choose the default program for running gulp to nodejs variable path .

or , two , just uninstall the gulp and re install it .

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you explain the first one.